# remove specific class's using jQuery and regExp

Tags: jquery, css, regex

I am trying to find all classes that have the characters ‘-color’ in it and then remove the classes found.

I have a bunch of classes like `blue-color` and `red-color`. I want to select all class names like these using a regexp. I have read many posts but have not found out how to make it work in my situation.

When you click on the social icons they disappear along with the home link(logo) and the rest of the nav looses its color. Basically my script is adding a twitter-color class and Facebook-color class to the rest of the nav which breaks it. I don't want my script to add any class to the nav when the social icons are clicked and i am having a hard time trying to figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: [A jsFiddle to experiment in](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/9tAPv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass in a function as the argument to the remove class:

```
function (index_in,classes_in){
    var classes = classes_in.split(" ");
    for(var i=0; i < classes.length ; i++)
       if(!/.*-color.*/.test(classes[i]))
          classes.splice(i,1);
    var toRemove = classes.join(" "); 
    return toRemove;
}
```

that should do the trick

Comment: All of these work but i still am unable to implement into my own code. If anyone has the time to figure out why it doesnt work i can send you my github link. Thank you everyone for your input so far.

Comment: I think that the problem with the disappearing icons is that you don't have any css attached to the twitter-color or facebook-color classes that you replace the home-color class with. When this happens the background url you have is replaced by nothing causing it to disappear

Comment: it adds a class of twitter color of facebook color depending on which one was clicked to the rest of the nav which cause everything to break and disappear. Can't figure out how to not add the twitter-color class to the rest of the nav when clicked.

Comment: Thats happening in the mainNavControlFunction line 55 & 61 of satori.js. First you remove all classes from your facebook and twitter icons then all of the classes from the main-nav icons and finish it off by adding the slideColor which will be either home-color, twitter-color, or facebook-color

Comment: I dont want it to create a twitter-color or a facebook-color class.the class that changes the color is made dynamically by grabbing the current links ID and then appending '-color' to it. so you would get home-color, about-color and so on. i don't want it to do this when you click on either of the social icons in the nav. only the home-color,about-color,solutions-color, approach-color and contact-color exist in my css. hope that makes since and i appreciate you taking time out to help me with this.

Comment: My suggestion wo be to put the code from lines 54-61 in an if block that's logic would run like `if(id != "facebook" && id != "twitter"){..code..}`. I wouldn't mind an up vote and for you to accept my answer! ;)

Comment: That's actualy what i ended up doing but now when you click on the social links the active state goes away in the nav. Thanks for your help Legion!

Comment: Sweet! No problem! Please remember to choose it as your selected answer.  The line of code making the active state go away is on line 110. Most likely you will need to have another condition in the if statement checking the id of the `$(this)` element

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/TMFWx/)):

```js
$("#facebook, #twitter").removeClass(function(_, currentClassValue) {
    var currentClasses = currentClassValue.split(/\s+/);
    var classesToRemove = $.grep(currentClasses, function(currentClass) {
        return /-color$/.test(currentClass);
    });
    return classesToRemove.join(" ");
});
```

It uses [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) with a function to remove only some classes, [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to parse the `class` attribute, and [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if each class ends in “-color”. It uses [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter `currentClasses` down to just ones for which the function returns `true`, in order to get an array of just the classes to remove.

I assumed that you really wanted to remove classes that *end* with “-color”, but if you want to remove classes that *contain* “-color” anywhere in the name, just change `/-color$/` to `/-color/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Jquery selector  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
    $(function(){
        $("[class*='-color']").each(function(){        
             $('#facebook,#twitter').removeClass($(this).attr("class"));
         });  

         $('#facebook,#twitter').addClass('anotherClass');
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tAPv/5/)

Comment: Your code won't work with `<div id="facebook" class="orange-color another-class">`, because the `class` doesn't end with "-color".

Comment: You may want `class*='-color'`.

Comment: Your code also removes too many classes. It will turn my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578766/remove-specific-classs-using-jquery-and-regexp/17579284#comment25579252_17579296)'s example div into `<div id="facebook">`, but you want `<div id="facebook" class="another-class">`.

Comment: that can be achieved by a addClass chain. I just answered to title question.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane updated fiddle and answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option, which is slightly more complex than need be:

```
$('#demo').find('[class]').attr('class', function(_, c) {
    var classes = c.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = classes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (classes[i].indexOf('-color') > -1) {
            classes[i] = '';
        }
    }
    return classes.join(' ');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6whV3/1/).

Though obviously, replace `#demo` with `#twitter, #facebook`.

Comment: You can view problem here http://travismichael.net/satori-website/ When you click on the social icons they disappear along with the home link(logo) and the rest of the nav looses its color. Basically my script is adding a twitter-color class and Facebook-color class to the rest of the nav which breaks it. I don't want my script to add any class to the nav when the social icons are clicked and i am having a hard time trying to figure it out.

Thank you